# Cannot Send Email From Google App Script With Table HTML Template

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to send an email from google app script with a table (html template). The data are from a Web App Form that user submit. but I got this error at `htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();`

Error:

> Uncaught  at eval at eval at processForm1 (Code:88)

Here's my .gs code:

```
 function processForm1(formObject) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11X8e10TGQwzUQVJzTJ24JB1KMCTzkL5F5vObKrH0__k/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");

  var headThings = ws.getRange("I1:I4").values; //header table is a merged cells
  var headWeight = ws.getRange("J1:J4").values; //header table is a merged cells

  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
  htmlTemplate.headThings = headThings;
  htmlTemplate.headWeight = headWeight;
  htmlTemplate.things = formObject.things;
  htmlTemplate.weight = formObject.weight;

  var htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent(); //error in this line

  var emailAddress = formObject.email;
  var subject = 'Table Detail';

  var message = 'Here's your table detail: ';
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {htmlBody: htmlForEmail});
}
```

Here's my email.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>
      <h1>Table Details</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><?= headThings ?></th><th><?= headWeight ?></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
         <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><?= things ?></td><td><?= weight ?></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there anything I did wrong? Your response will be appreciated :)

**EDIT**

So here's the flow:

First, user submit a Form contain `email` , `things` and `weight`, and then the copy of the submitted field will be emailed (in a table form) to the user email. The header of the tables are from the google sheet header cells.

Comment: I think that you script in your question occurs no error while `headThings` and `headWeight` ara undefined, because `values` of `ws.getRange(###).values` is undefined. So I thought that your error might not from your this script. I'm worry about this. How about this? If your current script in your question occur the error of `Uncaught at eval at eval at processForm1`, can you provide the detail flow for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike Hey I just update the post hope it would help you to understand the flow :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, your current script in your question occur the error of `Uncaught at eval at eval at processForm1`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yupp the error occur on the 'evaluate().getContent();' code line

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate the issue from your script in your question. And I couldn't understand about the method for replicating your issue from your updated question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So when I could replicate your issue, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you call `processForm1(formObject)` - please provide a sample `formObject` that would reproduce your problem. What is the content of your line 88?